# How are DOM/rendered html and Coded-Ui are related, can coded-ui test a web application without even considering how that page is rendered in DOM?

Tags: html, dom, coded-ui-tests

I want to know how the coded-ui in web application utilizes DOM of that page. Or is it related to that page's rendered html is coming?

Edited: If suppose i have a grid having rows and column and i want to capture any particular column in it, then do coded-ui takes the help of the rendered html in this process (id,tagname etc) ?

Comment: more details are needed, check this blog for info: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/tag/coded-ui-test/

Comment: when codedui runs a test he is playing back previously set steps (wheter recorded or programmed) - that means he cannot get in real time the id's and tags of rendered controls. those must be set in advanced. but it doesn;t mean that you cannot generic methods to handle controls (i.e tables/grids...). in addition - many controls have build in functionality that can be utilized (i.e htmlTable has a GetContent()\GetCell() etc...)

Comment: yeah, adding to your point we can make use of jquery in code-ui tests, see below link:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/10/21/coded-ui-tests-for-jqueryui.aspx]  <br/>
 
[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b86ab60e-19d0-456c-ae92-cc071e71a3bd/interaction-between-jquery-and-coded-ui-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used codedui jquery extensions available in NuGet [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fgautamg%2Farchive%2F2010%2F01%2F05%2Fseries-on-coded-ui-test-extensibility.aspx&ei=JHBIVYW1DZCMuAThvoCQDA&usg=AFQjCNFuUO9Ku2Rx0IwA9ZsREJTKquR14A&bvm=bv.92291466,d.c2E)
. Once you will add this dll as a reference you can make use ExecuteScript() method for running a jquery script inside coded-ui. Similary you can make use of other built in members.

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the htmlcontrols which is listed in below url:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.htmlcontrols.aspx